# How to send a sqs queue msg to an API, after hours?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have an AWS Lambda function integrated with an SQS (Simple Queue Service) queue that includes a Dead Letter Queue (DLQ) for storing failed messages. Our goal is to implement a retry mechanism: once a message lands in the DLQ, we aim to wait for 6 hours before re-attempting to send it back to the main queue for further processing, eventually forwarding it to a Spring Boot service.

While AWS Lambda functions have a maximum runtime of 15 minutes, orchestrating an action after precisely 6 hours poses a challenge. To address this, we explore a custom solution rather than relying on the built-in SQS redrive feature.

We've devised a process where an AWS Lambda function is triggered upon messages entering the DLQ. This function, acting as a delay mechanism, will effectively 'hold' the message for 6 hours before reinserting it into the main processing queue. Subsequently, the message is then sent to the Spring Boot service for handling.

EDIT: I have the visibilitytimeout in the queue, but i need to retry sending the msg to an api service which is in my lambda, once again (after it failed, that's why we want to retry in 6 hours).

This approach offers flexibility and control over the retry mechanism, allowing us to tailor it to our specific use case.
Here's our code:
`def move_messages_to_source_queue(dlq_url, source_url, visibility_timeout, delay_seconds):
print("Entering move_messages_to_source_queue.")

```
while True:
    try:
        response = sqs_client.receive_message(
            QueueUrl=dlq_url,
            MaxNumberOfMessages=1
        )

        messages = response.get('Messages', [])
        if not messages:
            logger.error("No messages in DLQ")
            break

        message = messages[0]
        receipt_handle = message['ReceiptHandle']

        # Change the visibility timeout and delete the message in one operation
        sqs_client.change_message_visibility(
            QueueUrl=dlq_url,
            ReceiptHandle=receipt_handle,
            VisibilityTimeout=visibility_timeout
        )

        sqs_client.delete_message(
            QueueUrl=dlq_url,
            ReceiptHandle=receipt_handle
        )

        # Send the message back to the source queue
        sqs_client.send_message(
            QueueUrl=source_url,
            MessageBody=message['Body']
        )
        
        msg_to_send = json.dumps(message['Body'])
        msg_info = f" Moved message from DLQ back to source queue: {msg_to_send}"
        logger.info(msg_info)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        # Handle the error as needed

    # Introduce a delay before processing the next message}
    print("Delay")
    time.sleep(delay_seconds)`
```

For sending info to the service we have in another method:
`response= requests.post(url, json=post_data, headers=headers_input)`

As you can see, the function tries to move the msg from the dlq to the main one, but the retry to the service in 6 hours is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Forget all that.

Use the `Delay Queue` (delayseconds) and `Visibility Timeout` to manipulate how long the messages languish in the queue.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html

[image: AWS Docs on SQS Delay queues]

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html

[image: Screenshot of AWS Docs on visibility timeouts]

Comment: Which one should be used? The Visibility Timeout has a threshold of twelve hours so that should be sufficient, no?

Comment: The OP wants to delay retries of failed messages, so I'm thinking they apply a 6 hour delay to the DLQ/redrive.  I confess I'm not sure if they can apply it directly to the DLQ, or need to set up a specific queue to point the redrive function at.  Either way, I'm pretty confident this approach is going to be 'better' than any lambda with "sleep" timeouts :-)

Comment: I would choose Visibility Timeout in this scenario as it can be set when read/write from the queue and satisfies the 6-hour grace period, however the SQS delay pools are new to me. Thanks for the tidbit. :)

Comment: i already have it, but i need to send the message to an api service after 6 hours, i meant the msg goes from dlq to the main queue and then it'll be process in a lambda.

Comment: @DidierMosley Sorry, I don't understand you. You can keep it retrying in the main queue for 6 hours by setting `maxReceiveCount` to 6, and the visibilty timeout to 60mins, That gives it 7 attempts over 6 hours; thence it fails to your DLQ+lambda.  I don't think it good practice to feed it back into the main queue after 6 hours.  Create another queue for those, as they are a special case.  Just one goal per queue is wisest.

Comment: Alright, i'll try, thank you sir, God Bless you, Christ Loves you.